# jQuery: scroll menu with mouseover

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll, mouseover

I'm looking for an menu similar to the one one mercedes.com site >
http://www3.mercedes-benz.com/mbcom_v4/de/en.html

When you click on the combobox in the second box on the left, 
a menu appears with a certain hight and the possiblity to 
scroll up and down on mouseover.

Does anybody know a plugin to realize this or has an hint how
to do it?

thx
Florian

Answer (score 1):

http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/

Would get you started on writing your own version of this, assuming you have some basic ability in javascript/jQuery. It basically makes a UL scrollable - you'd just have to make it appear when your on-screen element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this MouseOver Auto Scroller Menu Using jQuery and CSS http://articles.tutorboy.com/?p=2524